# eclipse pde maven - repository url reference for eclipse workbench objects

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm developing an eclipse plugin that requires access to various eclipse.ui.* classes.

Since I need to migrate this stuff into a maven archetype, the pom.xml requires a reference to a repository.

What is the Eclipse mandated p2 repository URL for use with org.eclipse.ui.workbench subcomponents? ... which is also maven compatible ?

Comment: You need to use Eclipse [tag:tycho] to deal with building Eclipse plug-ins, RCPs with maven. The Tycho maven extensions understand how to use Eclipse repositories. For example [see here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

Comment: @greg-449 it can't use eclipse repositories unless they're defined ... and i want to know the URL of the repository

Comment: For Tycho you just use the standard Eclipse release p2 repository `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-06` for Eclipse 2023-06 for example.

Comment: ... i was sure i tried this url at some point ... but apparently not. thank you @greg-449